# Where can I download the Soyuz Crew Operations Manual?

Tags: spacecraft, soyuz-spacecraft, reference-request

Where can I  download the Soyuz Crew Operations Manual?

Comment: Mark Vande Hei, is that you?

Comment: @bob why do you need this? are you going to steal a Soyuz? 

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I can't recall where I got them from, so let me just re-host.

[Crew-ops manual](https://mega.nz/file/O15UmQ6K#i20Fmj18cd6H562ZQGnT4Thgz0qc0fABjQh_DqE_LPk)

[Users manual](https://mega.nz/file/DlgwxI4J#UGk3N5SpGLT4Eu6lBT27M-frEfqmeW1lg7mpr7KI4Kw)

Comment: Manual could use some revision " the most frequently launched rocket in the world and the only  manned  vehicle  offered  for  commercial  space  launches."

Comment: Sorry, it has a couple years.

Comment: Probably want to share it on IPFS or something, for the situation when MEGA eventually goes down

Comment: maybe someone can mirror it over to archive.org, too